# Way to reset Android HOME Screen Default?

Tags: android, homescreen

I am recently working on a Parental Control Home Screen.

Noted from research says there are no way to code direct set my apps as default, but am thinking to provide a button for user to ops reset the default?  So after pressing the reset button, user will able to chose a new default Home Screen when press on HOME button.

Any hints or though for doing so?

---

**EDIT**

Noted this reset action is prohibited for security reasons.  Maybe I should change to another option: When user pressed a button, it will bring out the set HOME SCREEN default option?

All I need to do is to provide a much straight forward way for my app user to set my app as the default Home Screen.  The user might have limited experience or even new to Android system.  Perhaps they might be new to computer equipment as well.  So I need a simple way to let them achieve the setting.

Please enlighten me.  TQ.